# Implement ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've been trying to add ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework into my project but I always get the same results.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFErrorUtilities", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have been following steps from Facebook's and Parse's getting started guide.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users

EDIT - Did another attempt with no success and same error.

Here is a list of all current frameworks in the app

```
Social.framework
Accounts.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
StoreKit.framework
Security.framework
QuartzCore.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CFNetwork.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
Bolts.framework
Parse.framework
ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework
FBSDKLoginKit.framework
FBSDKCoreKit.framework
```

And my bridging header.

```
#ifndef MY_Bridging_Header_h
#define MY_Bridging_Header_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

#endif
```

Please let me know if there's any other information you need!

Comment: What's the version of your ParseFacebookUtilsV4?

Comment: CocoaPods would solve all your issues and make your life a breeze. I suggest using it!

Comment: @SanitLee - I used the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework from the current parse-library-1.8.2. Which should be 1.8.

Comment: @kelvinlau - I duplicated the project and tried with CocoaPods as well. 
Below is my Podfile
---
target 'app' do

 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
 pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
 pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'

end

target 'appTests' do

end
---
My current question is.. what's next? When I load the workspace, this line "import ParseFacebookUtilsV4" causes "no such modules..."

Thank you both!!

Comment: @JSIM so make sure both **Facebook-iOS-SDK** and **ParseFacebookUtils** removed as they're deprecated, then clean and rebuild the project.